# Should I use null for the value of a number - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want an input to initially be set to empty so I set the input's ngModel to null.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="expenses" (keyup)="onKey($event)">
```

The model is used like this:

```
expenses: number = null;

...

if (this.expenses.toString() === '') {
  this.inputHelperTextVisible = false;
}
```

Should I use null on a number?

Comment: You can use condition like `if (this.expenses == null || this.expenses == "")` so it will not create any problem when object is Empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should use nullable operator '?'.

```js
expenses?: number = null;

...

if (this.expenses === null) {
  this.inputHelperTextVisible = false;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, this.expenses === null is false when input is '' (empty)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can actually, if you want your model state to start at no value.

And also if you want numbers only make sure to make your input to a type number

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="expenses" (keyup)="onKey($event)"/>
```

set stackblitz below for the complete guide
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-26ftr7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
expenses?: number = null;

if (this.expenses === null || this.expenses === '') {
this.inputHelperTextVisible = false;
}
```